# How to properly name and conceptualize object data modeling scenario with a Quote object that contains Line Items?

Tags: php, refactoring, repository-pattern, data-modeling, naming

This is a object/data modeling and object naming question.

**Background**

Imagine you are getting a repair quote for a vehicle - you usually get a single sheet, which is called a quote, and on the sheet there are one or more line items indicating repairs to be done, with pricing, quantity, description information.  The quote itself has things like customer name, business name, company logo, address, formatting, etc.

Suppose I write a `Quote` object, where a quote has zero or more instances of `LineItem`.

Consider the following code:

```
class LineItemRepository extends GenericRepository
{
    /**
     * Return Quote Domain entity, populated with line items and metadata
     */
    function getQuote(int $quoteId): Quote
    {
        //selects all line items that belong to a quote with quote_id
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()->createQuery('
            SELECT item
            FROM ' . LineItem::class . ' item
            WHERE item.quoteId = :quote_id
        ');
        $query->setParameter('quote_id', $quoteId);  
        $lineItems = $query->getResult();

        //creates & populates a domain Quote object with 
        //quote metadata and line items
        $quoteData = $this->getDoctrine()->find(Quote::class, $quoteId);
        $quote = new Quote($quoteData);
        $quote->setLines($lineItems);
        return $quote;
    }
}
```

Above I have a `LineItemRepository` that is conceptually "in charge" of managing individual line items, where line items are a part of a quote.  So inside my `getQuote` method I request all the line items using Doctrine ORM, where line items belong to a particular quote, with a given quote id.  The method returns a `Quote` object, where the object contains quote metadata (customer info, etc), and line items with their own metadata (quantity, description, etc)

To me this creates a *dissonance*.  How can a repository that is in charge of individual line items, return a quote, when a `Quote` is a separate entity almost, which is not a `LineItem`?  Those are separate concepts and somehow they are mixed together.  Shouldn't it return .. just line items in a group perhaps, like an array for example?

Do I or should I rename `LineItemRepository` to `QuoteRepository` instead to help remove this dissonance?  Do I keep things as is?  I am pretty confused.  How do I name things and how do I conceptualize these concepts in my head so that object data modeling makes sense and naming reflects this understanding, and that there is no dissonance?

I am struggling because `LineItem` and `Quote` are concepts that are pretty-well connected, and yet separate.  `LineItem` does not make sense by itself, without being attached to a quote conceptually, so naming things is kind of hard, as they are connected, yet separate.

Comment: I would probably just name it `ItemsRepository` and have a method called `getItemsByQuoteId(int $id)`. Then I would have a `QuotesRepository` that uses the `ItemsRepository` to get the items when you're fetching a quote. However, this is just my opinion. There are many ways of solving this.  Most answers will be opinions which is why this question actually is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

When we talk about SOLID, the S stands for Single Responsability Principle, which means that the class should have only one reason to change.

In this case, the code you have may change both when the `Quote` or `Line` changes.

What you could do is to create/use a class named `Quote` and create a method `getQuote`, `getQuoteLines`, `getQuoteItems` or something, that will return the quote itself with the lines, because the `Quote` is a composition of `Line`, at least in the conception, and know the `Lines`.
In the other way, a `Line` knows itself and the `Quote` it belongs, but a `Line` doesn't know their siblings, thats why you should give the responsability to the `Quote` class.